# Regex to match any character without trailing / leading whitespace + min / max length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to figure out how to match following values via preg_match using:

```
^[\S].*[\S]{3,10}$
```

Unfortunately, the min works from size of 4 and the max of 10 is being ignored at all as the pattern still machtes on a lenght of 11.

1. Disallow leading and trailing spaces
2. Allow any character inside
3. Allow space within characters
4. Enforce min of 3 and max of 10 (not working)

Testset that could be used with: https://www.phpliveregex.com

```
[
    [
        "Test",
        true
    ],
    [
        "Test Test",
        true
    ],
    [
        "Test-Test",
        true
    ],
    [
        "Test'Test",
        true
    ],
    [
        "Test,Test",
        true
    ],
    [
        null,
        false
    ],
    [
        "   ",
        false
    ],
    [
        " Test ",
        false
    ],
    [
        "12",
        false
    ],
    [
        "12345678901",
        false
    ]
]
```

Thanks for your help in advanced

Comment: It would be helpful to readers if you would begin your question with a statement of the problem without reference to your regex, followed by one or more examples, showing the desired result for each and then present the code you have tried and explain why it is faulty (not just here, but for SO questions generally).

Comment: Use `^(?=.{4,10}$)\S.*\S$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/LfbLWa/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{4,10}$)\S.*\S$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IMbwXz/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{4,10}$)` - four to ten chars other than line break chars up to the end of string allowed
- `\S`  - a non-whitespace char
- `.*`  - 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\S`  - a non-whitespace char
- `$` - end of string.